# Doctrine2: efficient mapping of inherited class

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, symfony

I've a problem figuring out how to configure the mapping of my classes with Doctrine2.

Let say I've these tables:

```
Address table 
--------------------- 
- id 
- civic_no 
- road 
- state 
- country 

PersonnalAddress table 
--------------------- 
- id 
- base_address_id 
- type 
- is_primary 

BusinessAddress table 
--------------------- 
- id 
- base_address_id 
- business_name 
- shipping_phone 
- is_primary
```

And thoses PHP objects:

```
class Address{}
class BusinessAddress extends Address{}
class PersonalAddress extends Address{}
```

Considering the following requirements:

- An address can exist by itself (the Address class is not abstract)
- A personalAddress and a businessAddress can have the very same address data
- If I delete or edit the address, it has an impact on all the business or personal address that are inherited from it.
- I don't want any data duplication in the database (this is a requirement of the 2nd normal form)
- Proxy methods mean code duplication, I prefer not to have any.
- Magic methods are not good in term of testability, I prefer not to have any.

To better illustrate the problem, I expect the data in the data base to look like:

```
Address table:
id | civic_no | road | state | country
 1        123   test      qc        ca

PersonnalAddress table:
id | base_address_id | type | is_primary 
 1                 1      A            0
 2                 1      B            1

BusinessAddress table:
id | base_address_id | business_name | shipping_phone | is_primary 
 1                 1       chic choc          1231234            1
```

What would be the best strategy to implement a solution that match theses requirements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is a bit of a long one but I think it covers all your bases, if you have any questions then feel free to ask.

This comes with a caveat that I don't know if you can do `Many-To-One` on a MappedSuperclass. If that isn't possible then you may be able to use Class Table Inheritance instead. Give it a try and tell us if it works.

Keep in mind I pushed this code out pretty quickly, it is untested so it may not be correct but hopefully you'll get the idea of how it works.

**Here we go!**

Interface to make it easier to say "what is an address" without making abstract classes then overriding methods and causing the "bad design" feeling ;)

```
interface Address {

    function getCivicNo();

    function getRoad();

    function getState();

    function getCountry();
}
```

Abstract Entity which you don't really need but if you dont use it you need to duplicate the ID code.

```
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class AbstractEntity {

    /**
     * Entity ID column.
     * 
     * @var integer
     * 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    public function getId() {
        return $id;
    }

}
```

BasicAddress which you can store alone or have linked to a "ComplexAddress"

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class BasicAddress extends AbstractEntity implements Address {

    /** @ORM\Column() */
    private $road;

    public function getRoad() {
        return $this->road;
    }

    // etc etc

}
```

"ComplexAddress" is just here to let you re-use the code for delegating calls to a basic address.

```
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class ComplexAddress extends AbstractEntity implements Address {

    /** @ORM\Many-To-One(targetEntity="BasicAddress")
    private $basicAddress;

    public function __construct(BasicAddress $basicAddress) {
        $this->basicAddress = $basicAddress;
    }

    public function getRoad() {
        return $this->basicAddress->getRoad();
    }

    // other methods for implementing "Address" just delegate to BasicAddress

}
```

PublicAddress

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class PersonalAddress extends ComplexAddress {

    /** @ORM\Column(type="boolean") */
    private $isPrimary;

    public function isPrimary() {
        return $isPrimary;
    }

    // other personal address methods here

}
```

BusinessAddress

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class BusinessAddress extends ComplexAddress {

    /** @ORM\Column() */
    private $businessName;

    public function getBusinessName() {
        return $this->businessName;
    }

    // other business address methods here

}
```

Edit: Just noticed I forgot to put cascade parameters for deletion, you might need to handle this directly though - when a `BasicAddress` is deleted also delete the other addresses that use it.

Comment: I think it might work, the manual says: "This means that One-To-Many associations are not possible on a mapped superclass at all.", and the other 2 types of inheritance wouldn't work as you need a discriminator field that render impossible for 2 different types to have the same parent.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extending the **Address** class, you'll have to create a **OneToMany** relationship on the **Address** and a **ManyToOne** relationship on the **PersonalAddress** and **BusinessAddress**. Something like this:

```
<?php

// ...

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

// ...
class Address
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PersonalAddress", mappedBy="address")
     */
    private $personalAddresses;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BusinessAddress", mappedBy="address")
     */
    private $businessAddresses;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->personalAddresses = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->businessAddresses = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}
```

And, for the child classes:

```
<?php

// ...

// ...
class PersonalAddress
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Address", inversedBy="personalAddresses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="base_address_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $address;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but why do my Address object has to know about personalAddress and businessAddress ? Also, how will I access the Address method from the PersonnalAddress class without using proxy method ?

Comment: You mean, how do can you access the  ```Address``` class from the ```PersonalAddressClass```? Create getters and setters running ```doctrine:generate:entities``` and you can do ```$personalAddress->getAddress()```.

Comment: That was my first implementation attempt. From a PHP perspective, it's really not what I want. The person who'll use the class now have to handle the object has 2 objects. So to be able to use the object has a unified object, I would have to create proxy method, like in personAddress, businessAddress, etc... that look like: public function getStreet(){ return $this->address->getRoad(); } and that's a very bad practice (event if it seem well used in the doctrine community)

Comment: Why? You can just write: ```$businessAddress->getAddress()->getRoad()```.

Comment: I don't want the users who use the code to have to understand the logics behind the object. They use a business address, that's it. That's why I want to use inheritance, and now relations, as you could do 100% of the OO needs with relations only, and never use extends, but that would not be nice and intuitive. ;)

Comment: Well, if you extend a Doctrine entity you'll duplicate that entity's fields and you can't create a relationship.